# Joomla 3.x, include menu items in search results

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I've built several sites using Joomla and think it's a pretty decent framework to work with. However, one thing that really bugs me is that menu items don't show in the search results (com_search).

All I get is articles, contacts, weblinks, categories and news feeds which are all completely irrelevant to my needs. Right now, all I get in the results are links to articles (for example) which leads to that article but leaves out all the good stuff you get when accessing it through a menu item such as modules.

So what I really want to know is if it's possible to force the search component to include menu items and leave out stuff that is unnecessary?

**EDIT**

You know what, having reviewed my code and all that I've realised that my original question was a bit misleading. Now, what I REALLY want to accomplish is to restrict Joomlas com_search to ONLY search published menu items and nothing else. Is this possible?

Comment: I am slightly confused, are you getting a different link to an article via menu compared to opening it using search?

Comment: Are you talking about smart search or unsmart search?

Comment: @MarkoD: The links I get points to the correct articles, however they leave out their associated Itemid:s so Joomla doesn't realise that it has a menu object with modules and stuff like that connected to it.

Elin: Unsmart, I guess. Standard com_search behaviour.